# Can't boot Windows 10 in QEMU, only flashing cursor

Tags: windows, virtual-machine, kvm, qemu

I'm trying to do a Windows 10 install on qemu, but I only get a quick Windows logo flash and then I'm stuck on a flashing cursor (I left it running for 10+ minutes and it didn't work). On `top` I see `qemu-system-x86_64` using 100% CPU, however.

Thinking my old ISO might be corrupted, I downloaded a new one from Microsoft and still the problem persists.

My command line is `qemu-system-x86_64 -cdrom ./Win10_21H2_BrazilianPortuguese_x64.iso -drive file=Windows10.qcow2,format=qcow2 -m 8192 -vga std -enable-kvm -boot menu=on`, but even without any parameters (i.e. `qemu-system-x86_64 -cdrom ./Win10_21H2_BrazilianPortuguese_x64.iso -m 2048`) I still get the same problem.

With the same settings (only replacing the ISO), I can successfully boot a Linux image (Fedora 36 live-CD), which makes me think the problem is Windows.

I am using qemu version 6.2.0 on Fedora 36. Both ISO and hard drive image are on a NVMe SSD. What am I missing here?

Comment: Have you tried with `virt-manager`? How did you setup the **Windows10.qcow2** file?

Comment: @ajgringo619 by `qemu-img create -f qcow2 Windows10.qcow2 100G`. Haven't tried virt-manager yet, will try it later

Comment: only a wild guess ... maybe windows does not detect a display with adequate resolution

Comment: @ajgringo619 with virt-manager it works.